# Append to a Select Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Gridview that I want to filter. My gridview is in an update panel and my filter button is not. On button click i have the following

```
protected void bttnfilter_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != "")
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand += " and field like '%' + @param + '%'";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString );
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", TextBox1.Text));
    }

}
```

So i add to the select command but I'm getting an error. How should I go about this? I don't want to use dynamic sql.

**The Error Reads**
Incorrect Syntax near 'and'

Comment: "I'm getting an error" What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the original `SelectCommand`'s value?

Comment: What is the value of SQLDataSource1.SelectCommand ? You can print this.

Comment: Try using the actual value of your variables and see what happens, this way you'll know if its an error in your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
private void bttnfilter_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string filterText = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = 
            string.Format("field LIKE '%{0}%'",filterText);         
}
```

Comment: It's saying it can't find my column field

Comment: @Eric - this assumes that field is the name of a field in a database *table*. You will need to change the name to the name of the field in question

Comment: Russ thank you. I had it as v.field. I changed it to Field. It worked just like you said. +1 also. thanks

Comment: Russ. Could you explain to me the string.Format part of this and how the {0} works? I would like to understand this a little better.

Comment: {0} is a placeholder in the format string for the ToString() representation of the first object in the object args that follow the format string. So, the output of `string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", myObject1, myObject2, myObject3)` would be equilvalent to the output of `myObject1.ToString() + " " + myObject2.ToString() + " " + myObject3.ToString()` . A lot easier to read isn't it (I'm not 100% on the performance of it compared to concatenation, perhaps someone who know for certain can answer that?)

Comment: why do you think i am having an issue using numbers? i get this error:

Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.

this is the code:

SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression =
            string.Format("MANUFACTURECODE = '%{0}%'", int.Parse (filterTextMC));

Comment: sorry code looks like this

SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression += 
                string.Format("MANUFACTURECODE = {0}", int.Parse (filterTextMC));

Comment: Because you can't call int.Parse on that text in the object arguments (which is only going to have .ToString() called on it anyway). Remember that the string you're building is a SQL string where numerical values will be represented as unquoted strings to be executed by the DB engine

Comment: Also, if you're adding to an existing FilterExpression then you'll need to prefix with AND . The FilterExpression translates to a WHERE clause essentially

Comment: YEah. I figured it out right after I asked. Thanks for your help Russ. Expect Points soon.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are appending to a query without `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
        AND field LIKE '%test%'
```

will give you this error.

Make you query stub as follows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   1 = 1
```

, which will select everything unless you append additional conditions to it.

In your case, this will give:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND field LIKE '%test%'
```

, which is a valid query.

> I don't want to use dynamic sql.

You *are* using it.

You better rewrite your query as this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   @param IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   field LIKE '%' + @param + '%'
```

and bind `NULL` if your text field is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the last clause in your SQL statement is a WHERE clause?  If there is no WHERE clause or if there's another clause after the WHERE (GROUP BY, ORDER BY) then you'll get this error.

Comment: You are right. It was an order by. But I changed it and it is saying that it can't find the scalar variable @param.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly either the lack of a where clause, or SelectCommand is referencing a stored procedure.